# Open map with routes pre charged from array with Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to work with Mapbox (because Maps now is paid) and my service is basically:

1. User create a route touching into the map
   ***The service takes the coordinate and create
2. The route created keeps saved in database (js or php, i have no idea about how is better to do this)
3. After close the windows, when the user come back to the website the routes (Step 1) will be there.

My actual problem is exactly show the route, i could not understand the documentation...
So, I'm using an array to take every click (and this is working), but how complete the next step (4)?

Code below:

```
    <script>
      var truckLocation = [-49.3766505877158, -20.80796326493855];
      var warehouseLocation = [-49.3766505877158, -20.80796326493855];
      var lastQueryTime = 0;
      var lastAtRestaurant = 0;
      var keepTrack = [];
      var currentSchedule = [];
      var currentRoute = null;
      var pointHopper = {};
      var pause = true;
      var speedFactor = 50;
      var capturaCoordenada = ['lat,long'];
      var exibeCoordenada ="";




      // Add your access token
      mapboxgl.accessToken = 'personal token';

      // Initialize a map
 
      var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container id
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10', // stylesheet location
        center: truckLocation, // starting position
        zoom: 15 // starting zoom
      });
var warehouse = turf.featureCollection([turf.point(warehouseLocation)]);
      map.on('load', function() {
  var marker = document.createElement('div');
  marker.classList = 'onibus';


// Create a new marker
var truckMarker = new mapboxgl.Marker(truckMarker)
.setLngLat(truckLocation)
.addTo(map);
});

// Create a circle layer
map.on('load', function() {
  map.addSource("points", {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": warehouseLocation
  })

map.addLayer({
  id: 'warehouse',
  type: 'circle',
  source: {
    data: warehouse,
    type: 'geojson'
  },
  paint: {
    'circle-radius': 20,
    'circle-color': 'white',
    'circle-stroke-color': '#4287f5',
    'circle-stroke-width': 3
  }
});

// Create a symbol layer on top of circle layer
map.addLayer({
  id: 'warehouse-symbol',
  type: 'geojs',
  source: {
    data: warehouse,
    type: 'geojson'
  },
  layout: {
    'icon-image': 'grocery-15',
    'icon-size': 1
  },
  paint: {
    'text-color': '#3887be'
  }
});


// Create an empty GeoJSON feature collection for drop-off locations
var dropoffs = turf.featureCollection([]);

map.addLayer({
  id: 'dropoffs-symbol',
  type: 'symbol',
  source: {
    data: dropoffs,
    type: 'geojson'
  },
  layout: {
    'icon-allow-overlap': true,
    'icon-ignore-placement': true,
    'icon-image': 'marker-15',
  }
});

// Listen for a click on the map
map.on('click', function(e) {
  // When the map is clicked, add a new drop-off point
  // and update the `dropoffs-symbol` layer
  newDropoff(map.unproject(e.point));
  updateDropoffs(dropoffs);
});
function newDropoff(coords) {
  // Store the clicked point as a new GeoJSON feature with
  // two properties: `orderTime` and `key`
  var pt = turf.point(
    [coords.lng, coords.lat],
    {
      orderTime: Date.now(),
      key: Math.random()
    }
  );
  dropoffs.features.push(pt);
}

function updateDropoffs(geojson) {
  map.getSource('dropoffs-symbol')
    .setData(geojson);
}

// Create an empty GeoJSON feature collection, which will be used as the data source for the route before users add any new data
var nothing = turf.featureCollection([]);

map.addSource('route', {
  type: 'geojson',
  data: nothing
});

map.addLayer({
  id: 'routeline-active',
  type: 'line',
  source: 'route',
  layout: {
    'line-join': 'round',
    'line-cap': 'round'
  },
  paint: {
    'line-color': '#3887be',
    'line-width': [
      "interpolate",
      ["linear"],
      ["zoom"],
      12, 3,
      22, 12
    ]
  }
}, 'waterway-label');

// Here you'll specify all the parameters necessary for requesting a response from the Optimization API
function assembleQueryURL() {

  // Store the location of the truck in a variable called coordinates
  var coordinates = [truckLocation];
  var distributions = [];
  keepTrack = [truckLocation];

  // Create an array of GeoJSON feature collections for each point
  var restJobs = objectToArray(pointHopper);

  // If there are any orders from this restaurant
  if (restJobs.length > 0) {

    // Check to see if the request was made after visiting the restaurant
    var needToPickUp = restJobs.filter(function(d, i) {
      return d.properties.orderTime > lastAtRestaurant;
    }).length > 0;

    // If the request was made after picking up from the restaurant,
    // Add the restaurant as an additional stop
    if (needToPickUp) {
      var restaurantIndex = coordinates.length;
      // Add the restaurant as a coordinate
      coordinates.push(warehouseLocation);
      capturaCoordenada = coordinates; //Retorna a coordenada clicada
      capturaCoordenada.push();
     
      // push the restaurant itself into the array
      keepTrack.push(pointHopper.warehouse);
    }

    restJobs.forEach(function(d, i) {
      // Add dropoff to list
      keepTrack.push(d);
      coordinates.push(d.geometry.coordinates);

      // if order not yet picked up, add a reroute
      if (needToPickUp && d.properties.orderTime > lastAtRestaurant) {
        distributions.push(restaurantIndex + ',' + (coordinates.length - 1));
      }
    });
  }
  // Set the profile to `driving`
  // Coordinates will include the current location of the truck,
  return 'https://api.mapbox.com/optimized-trips/v1/mapbox/driving/' + coordinates.join(';') + '?distributions=' + distributions.join(';') + '&overview=full&steps=true&geometries=geojson&source=first&access_token=' + mapboxgl.accessToken;
}

function objectToArray(obj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  var routeGeoJSON = keys.map(function(key) {
    return obj[key];
  });
  return routeGeoJSON;
}
function newDropoff(coords) {
  // Store the clicked point as a new GeoJSON feature with
  // two properties: `orderTime` and `key`
  var pt = turf.point(
    [coords.lng, coords.lat],
    {
      orderTime: Date.now(),
      key: Math.random()
    }
  );
  dropoffs.features.push(pt);
  pointHopper[pt.properties.key] = pt;

  // Make a request to the Optimization API
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: assembleQueryURL(),
  }).done(function(data) {
    // Create a GeoJSON feature collection
    var routeGeoJSON = turf.featureCollection([turf.feature(data.trips[0].geometry)]);

    // If there is no route provided, reset
    if (!data.trips[0]) {
      routeGeoJSON = nothing;
    } else {
      // Update the `route` source by getting the route source
      // and setting the data equal to routeGeoJSON
      map.getSource('route')
        .setData(routeGeoJSON);
    }

    if (data.waypoints.length === 12) {

        for (var i = 0; i < capturaCoordenada.length; i++) {
        var lat = capturaCoordenada[lat];
        var long = capturaCoordenada[long];
        exibeCoordenada = exibeCoordenada + "\n" + capturaCoordenada[i] + capturaCoordenada[long]; }
        exibeCoordenada = exibeCoordenada + "\n";
        // for (var i = 0; i < capturaCoordenada.length; i+=2) {
        // var x = capturaCoordenada[i];
        // var y = capturaCoordenada[i+1];
        // exibeCoordenada = exibeCoordenada + "\n" + capturaCoordenada[x] + capturaCoordenada[y]; }
        // exibeCoordenada = exibeCoordenada + "\n";
        window.alert(exibeCoordenada);
        
    }
  });
}
map.addLayer({
  id: 'routearrows',
  type: 'symbol',
  source: 'route',
  layout: {
    'symbol-placement': 'line',
    'text-field': '▶',
    'text-size': [
      "interpolate",
      ["linear"],
      ["zoom"],
      12, 24,
      22, 60
    ],
    'symbol-spacing': [
      "interpolate",
      ["linear"],
      ["zoom"],
      12, 30,
      22, 160
    ],
    'text-keep-upright': false
  },
  paint: {
    'text-color': '#3887be',
    'text-halo-color': 'hsl(55, 11%, 96%)',
    'text-halo-width': 3
  }
}, 'waterway-label');

});     </script>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Could you elaborate more on what's wrong and what you're not sure how to do?

Comment: Supposing I had the values in my database, I need that when the user opens the site that values(coordinates) load in the map showing the route

Comment: If you save the route in the database with some id, could you use the id to look up the values you need?

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding as well. Maybe try rewriting some of your question with different phrasing and more background.

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to store in database the coordinates but elaborate the info in a Xml (gpx file) outpout, store in the database just the name of the file, and keep the file in a folder.
This was you can always have the possibility to download the route as gpx file or move it elsewhere or manually adjust it. Keeping coordinates in a database i personally think it is not a flexible solution.